# Quadratic in one

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a+b+c=0$. Does $1^2a+1b+c=0 \implies b^2 \geq 4ac \ $ ? Obviously we know the inequality holds in general, but does considering a "quadratic in one" imply this?

Comment: Depends on the values of $a , b $ and $c$ .

Comment: $\because a + b + c = 0$, any of the scenarios given may come : $ a + c = -b, b + c = -a, a + b = -c $.

Comment: And probably you are right, because I said it out of thought and not out of written work.

Comment: This only implies that a function of $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has a root of $1$. which obviously implies the discriminant is positive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're right (assuming $a$, $b$, $c$ are real). You can prove it in another way:

$$b=-a-c$$
$$b^2=a^2+c^2+2ac$$

Now, by the A.M.-G.M. inequality,
$$\frac{a^2+c^2}{2}\ge ac$$

Thus,
$$b^2\ge4ac$$

Using the quadratic method, you'd have to assume a quadratic like this:
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Clearly, $1$ is a root. The other root must be real as well if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real. So -
$$b^2\ge4ac$$

Comment: That was my reasoning as well. The $1$ is just a(an?) $x$ in disguise.

Comment: 'an' $x$  when said , so in written language too that is the right one, I suppose....

Answer (score 1):

$1^2a+1b+c=0$ means that $x=1$ is a solution of $ax^2+bx+c=0$

In general when $a\not=0$ the solutions are $x=\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and since $x=1$ is real you are correct that this directly implies $b^2\ge 4ac$

If $a=0$ then $4ac =0$ while $b^2 \ge 0$ so that is true too